# Continuity of the derivative operator in $L^2$ (ANSWERED)

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces

I'm trying to understand a proof that my professor wrote in his notes, which is the following.

> $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$, with $\Omega$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, is a complete Banach space.

He considered the specific case of $H^1(\Omega)$, but stated that it would be the same procedure for the general case and I understand that.

To prove the completeness, he, of course, started by introducing a Cauchy sequence ${u_k} \subset H^1(\Omega)$, which would imply that
$$\left\lVert u_h - u_k \right\rVert _{L^2}  \to 0\hspace{1mm} ; \hspace{6mm} \left\lVert \partial_j u_h - \partial _j u_k  \right\rVert_{L^2} \to 0 , \ j= 1, \ldots,n$$
Here I don't understand why he assumes that ${\partial_j u_k}$ is also a Cauchy sequence just by saying that ${u_k}$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: The $H^1$ norm is the sum of the $L^2$ norms of the function and each of its (weak) partial derivatives. The fact that $(u_k)_k$ is a Cauchy sequence _in $H^1$_ implies that _the $H^1$ norm_ is small for the difference of terms far enough into the sequence, which then implies that each $L^2$ norm that you mention in your question is small. Can you deduce it from this?

Comment: Oh now I understand it! Damn that was so obvious, I don't know why I didn't figure it out right away lol. Thank you so much for helping me!